# Gradle tasks shown in intellij but can not be run

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

I have a multi module project with the following structure:

1. root_project

   1. module1
   2. module2
   3. module3

I try to apply the java plug-in to all projects using the following code:

```
allprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    group = 'com.mysoftware'
    sourceCompatibility = 1.8
    version = '1.3'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

Additionally I add the javafx plugin to module3. The java and javafx tasks are now shown in the intellij gradle view, but when trying to execute them, I get this error:

```
Task 'jfxJar' not found in root project 'module3'.
```

Furthermore, running the `tasks` task show me that neither the java tasks nor the javafx tasks are available, despite being shown in the gradle view in intellij. 
I tried rebuilding and refreshing the whole project without success. I use the `Use default gradle wrapper` configuration.

Comment: This message is strange : `Task 'jfxJar' not found in root project 'module3'` : it looks like Gradle is considering `module3` project as a root project... do you have maybe a `settings.gradle` file in the subproject directories, in addition to the one in root project dir ?  if so, you need to delete theses unwanted `settings.gradle` files as it's not a valid setup

Comment: That indeed was the problem, I just started using gradle and I somehow overread this I guess... Thank you so much! Can I somehow mark your comment as correct answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message you got `Task 'jfxJar' not found in root project 'module3'` indicates that Gradle considers the subproject `module3` as a Root project: this can happen if you created a `settings.gradle` file in the sub-project directory, which is not a valid setup (only one `settings.gradle` file can exist in a multiproject build, located in the root directory)